# What is the best algorithm to use for face recognition with there is only one person in the training set

Tags: opencv, image-processing, classification, face-recognition

So how do one train eigen or fisher or LBP or any other algorithm when we are only dealing with one person without having to include other random people's faces like att_faces db.

I only want to have one person's face in the training set and compare and see if the give face is that person. I know you can have bunch of other people's face in the training and have it classify one and even get a vector distance of the classification but what I don't think it is safe if you are using it as a security measure, say, as a second factor authentication. I mean what if one of those random people in att_faces database actually use the system ?

So what is the best approach. It seems to me that we almost always have to train our system with a bunch of people's face as well as our face.

Think Iphone's touch fingerprint recognition. I am sure they don't have a bunch of random's people finger prints in there so that system can classify our finger prints against others.

Comment: if you have person X and persons A B C D to train the system, if you only want to grant person X access you just don't open the door if A B C or D are recognized ;) but there are obviously different problems...

Comment: Problem is i only want to have person X and only train it on person X.classification algorithms that I know dont work well for this sort of scenario

Comment: wss talking about your " I know you can have bunch of other people's face in the training and have it classify one and even get a vector distance of the classification but what I don't think it is safe if you are using it as a security measure, say, as a second factor authentication. I mean what if one of those random people in att_faces database actually use the system ? "

Comment: One-class SVM can work well in the case where one wants to determine if an input belongs to a class.  However, I believe you might be missing the power behind an algorithm that uses multiple labeled classes to train a feature extractor/similarity function that optimizes performance on identification or verification tasks.  While the iPhone may not contain all  fingerprints from training (in some representation), it isn't beyond reason that there is some trained model that was derived from a training set.  This model can be interpreted to encode inter/intra-class variation for fingerprints.